# How to toggle to camera view via python?

Tags: python, scripting, camera, scene

Is there a way to programmatically achieve the same thing as pressing the `0` key the numpad?

Comment: are you looking for the operator ?

Comment: if it is a `bpy.ops` thing that's fine, but I already "own" the `camera` and if I could assign it to a "view-slot" or something that would be awesome..

Comment: do you want to set which camera is used for this view ?, the 3d view can have it's own active camera without affecting thescene camera

Comment: What do you mean by "view slot"? Do you want to bind the camera to another key?

Comment: @poor nvm the phrase "view slot", I'm looking for a way to achieve what the first answer is about, but without swicthing the area-type

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The operator for switching the 3D view which is associated with numpad keys is `view3d.viewnumpad()`.  You have to be in the right context (3d_view) to use it and select which view you want to set:

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.view3d.viewnumpad(override, type = 'CAMERA')
        break
```

Another way, without the operator would be:

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_perspective = 'CAMERA'
        break
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
import bpy

area = next(area for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D')
area.spaces[0].region_3d.view_perspective = 'CAMERA'
```

Other options are  `[‘PERSP’, ‘ORTHO’, ‘CAMERA’]`

Comment: that is working if the area type is `'VIEW_3D'`, but is there another way, to achieve this thing without temporarily switch the area?

Comment: the context should be VIEW_3D , but you can do it without switching, I will edit

Comment: just to be sure: there is no other way, then using the `bpy.ops`, right? (btw switching back and forth is way shorter than the solution you have provided after the edit -- but I have no idea, what is the advantage of you way vs. the "switching" way)

Answer (score 3):

the best way is to put it into a function (e.g in the main of the template: simple operator)

```
def main(context):
    
    if context.region_data.view_perspective in  {'PERSP','ORTHO'}: 
        context.region_data.view_perspective = 'CAMERA'
    else:                            
        context.region_data.view_perspective = 'PERSP'
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

notice region_data
another example to not do a loop over areas...

```
def execute(self, context):
    context.space_data.overlay.show_extra_indices^= True
```

to switch show_extra_indices (edit mode)
show_extra_indices