# View3D operations problem

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

Currently i am trying to change the viewport of the 3D View window using a python script. I am using this function

```
bpy.ops.view3d.viewnumpad(type='TOP');
```

But it always get this error

> RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.viewnumpad.poll() failed,
>   context is incorrect

The same error is gotten when I use this function

```
bpy.ops.view3d.view_persportho();
```

Waht is the problem?

Comment: @Chebhou, I have already read this answer but it does not solved my question

Comment: can you edit your post with the new code to see the new problem

Comment: ok here is the exact answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30645/5113

Comment: @Chebhou, I have already used this code to achieve the ORTHO view but how can I achieve the TOP view?

Comment: @Chebhou, I need the code that do the same operation when click on 7

Comment: did you write `type='TOP'` and it didn't work, what error you're getting ?

Comment: @Chebhou, yes because the enum contains just CAMERA, ORTHO, PERSP. TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: enum "TOP" not found in ('PERSP', 'ORTHO', 'CAMERA')

Comment: don't use the second part use only the first (from the answer )

Comment: @Chebhou, What do you mean by the first part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26213/discussion-between-chebhou-and-startingblender).

Answer (score 3):

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == "VIEW_3D":
        break

for region in area.regions:
    if region.type == "WINDOW":
        break

space = area.spaces[0]

context = bpy.context.copy()
context['area'] = area
context['region'] = region
context['space_data'] = space

bpy.ops.view3d.viewnumpad(context, 'EXEC_DEFAULT', type='TOP')
bpy.ops.view3d.view_persportho(context, 'EXEC_DEFAULT')
```

or without operators:

```
from mathutils import Quaternion

r3d = space.region_3d
r3d.view_perspective = "ORTHO"
#default - look down z-axis
r3d.view_rotation = Quaternion((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

Comment: This is helpful since this works in 2.80 beta now compared to missing the viewnumpad completely now.