# Change 3d viewport to othrogonal in python

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

I would like to change the 3d viewport to orthogonal from a python script. From the key mapping I found this command "view3d.view_persportho". I always find it tricky when I have to mess with the context (Which I think is nescesary). Anyway, I tried this:

```
for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            for region in area.regions:
                if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                    override = bpy.context.copy()
                    override['area'] = area
                    override['region'] = region
                    override['scene'] = bpy.context.scene                      
                    bpy.ops.wm.setup_ui(override) 
                    # Maybe I can set perspective here somehow?

class MYOP_setup_ui(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.setup_ui"
    bl_label = "Setup UI"
    def execute(self, context):
        context.space_data.show_region_ui = True # This opens the sidebar panels correctly
        # I know that I can't pass arguments to operators like in the next line.
        # bpy.ops.view3d.view_persportho('ORTHO') # 'PERSP', 'CAMERA'            
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

I found these, which is pretty much what I want, but I can't get it to work. Maybe pre 2.8?

[View3D operations problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34488/view3d-operations-problem)

https://blenderartists.org/t/determine-whether-or-not-you-are-in-perspective-or-orthographic-view/617907

Comment: Does this answer your question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181110/what-is-the-python-command-to-check-if-current-view-is-in-orthographic-or-perspe

Comment: Yes thanks! context.space_data.region_3d.view_perspective = 'ORTHO'