# Is there a way to align the view to a non-active camera?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, edit-mode

I have multiple cameras setup in my scene at predetermined locations. Pressing `Numpad 0` will align the 3D view to the current **active** camera. Is there a way for me to align the view to a camera that isn't active?

I want to have multiple panes with each one aligned to a different camera while I'm working on the scene. Currently, I have to manually move the view in each one to be (roughly) in the same position as the camera I want to look through. It'd be better if I could automatically align the view to the exact location of any camera.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Both the UI and the python API don't offer a way to set the 3D view to a camera that isn't active, as far as I'm aware. See how to set it via python: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30643/how-to-toggle-to-camera-view-via-python

Comment: @rjg thanks for that link. Kinda disappointing this isn't a built in feature, but at least there's a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick workaround which provides approximation is to use *Align View to Active* command to align viewport camera to currently selected but not active render camera.

[image]

Roughly the procedure would look like:
1. Selecting camera you want to align viewport to.
2. Running *View Selected* command (as one way to center viewport to selection).
3. Running *Align View* > *Align View to Active* > *Top* (in 2.79 layout it was <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>).

Comment: Awesome! Not as clean as a built-in feature, but it's pretty much exactly what I needed, thanks!